# Pareto (80/20) Segmentation in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I created 80/20 segmentation in my Power BI data model and I got what I wanted (see the table below).
Now I want to calculate new Name column with the next logic: if Cumulative % <=80% show value from the "Customer Name" column, otherwise show "Other" (the result will be the column Name as in the table below).

I tried with this calculated column but it doesn't work (the result isn't correct, it's always "Other"):

```
80/20 Name = IF([Cumulative Percen.] <= 0.8, SalesReport[Names], "Other")
```

Note: "Cumulative Percen." is calculated measure.

How can I do this?

---

In the next step, I'll use a pie chart to show this segmentation where all customers with small cumulative transactions will be categorized as Other.

[image]

The calculated measures that I used:

```
Customer Rank by Transaction =
IF (
    HASONEVALUE ( SalesReport[CustName] ),
    RANKX (
        ALLSELECTED ( SalesReport[CustName] ),
        CALCULATE ( [# of Transactions] ),
        ,
        DESC,
        DENSE
    )
)
```

---

```
Customer Cumulative Transaction =
VAR CurrentCustimerRank = [Customer Rank by Transaction]
RETURN
    SUMX (
        FILTER (
            ALLSELECTED ( SalesReport[CustName] ),
            CALCULATE ( [Customer Rank by Transaction] ) <= CurrentCustimerRank
        ),
        CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( SalesReport[CustID] ) )
    )
```

---

```
Customer Cumulative Transaction Percen. =
[Customer Cumulative Transaction]
    / CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT ( SalesReport[CustID] ),
        ALLSELECTED ( SalesReport[CustName] )
    )
```

Comment: Are `Cumulative Transaction` and `Cumulative %` measures or calculated columns? Do you want `Name` as a measure or a calculated column? In either case, please give the DAX formulas for all measures and calculated columns involved.

Comment: @AlexisOlson __Cumulative Transaction__ and __Cumulative %__ are calculated measures.
New column __Name__ should be calculated column - since I want it to use as a category in the charts and graphs.

Comment: @AlexisOlson The the code for the calculated measures is in the answer below (too long for the comment).

Comment: I've edited them into the question (they don't belong as an answer).